# SQL Server - Multiple Processes Inserting to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a couple of stored procs (Add & Remove) which run some selects, inserts, deletes  & updates on some tables.  These seem fine.

Each of these procs uses a TRANSACTION.
I begin the transaction before I do any changes to data and near the end of the proc i do..

```
IF @@TRANSCCOUNT > 0
  COMMIT TRANSACTION @transName;
```

Within the Add and Remove procs, and within the TRANSACTION I call another stored procedure (Adjust) to update a table which keeps a running total of values.
I am finding that this is getting out of sync.....

Here is the body of that proc....

```
  INSERT INTO L2(ProductId, LocationId, POId, StockMoveId, BasketId, OrderId, AdjusterValue, CurrentValue)
    SELECT TOP 1 
      @ProductId, @LocationId, null, null, @BasketId, null, @Value, (CurrentValue + @Value)
    FROM L2
    WHERE 1=1
      AND LocationId = @LocationId
      AND ProductId = @ProductId
    ORDER BY Id Desc
```

ProductId, LocationId, StockMoveId and OrderId are all foreign keys to the relevent tables but do allow nulls so only the approprate one needs to be populated with an actual value.

Here is an image showing an example of where it goes wrong....
[image: Pic showing probelem]

The 19 should have been addded to 324 nmaking a new total of 343, however, as you can see it seems to have been added to the 300 and 319 is inserted.

Questions...
Is this actually in the transaction that was began in the calling stored proc.

How can I prevent this situation?

I've tried using MAX to get the right row to try and speed up  but the execution plan on that isn't as cost effective as the simple TOP.  ID, btw is an Identity column and PKey.

Do I need to Lock the table, and if I do with the other process calling Adjust wait or will they error.

Any assistance much appreciated.

More info....
I have been experimenting and it would seem the only solution that consistently works as desired is to have the Id column as an INT field and simply increment it myself on the INSERT.
This doesn't sit well with me as to me it doesn't make sense as to why the IDENTITY column n doesn't seem to cope.

I've tried the posted Identity column solution, sequences and incrementing ID myself

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching, experimenting I SEEM to have a solution that is now very robust.
I now have the ID as a simple INT column and I manage the ID myself by getting the MAX + 1 for each new insert.

I now wrap the body of the Adjust proc in its own Transaction and use the following to get the next ID.....

```
  DECLARE @trxNam Varchar(10) = 'tranNextId';
  DECLARE @newId INT;
  DECLARE @currentLevelId INT;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION @trxNam;
  SELECT @newId = MAX(id) + 1 FROM L2 WITH(updlock,serializable);
```

I then do my insert using the @newId and COMMIT the named transaction.
I have a scenarion set up where I have a number of Win32Apps caling my API 100s of times that was cosistantly failing due to intermittent PKEY violations.
Now it doesn't.

Happy days!
Still I'm looking to see if I can simply have an identity column again and use the Transaction in the adjust proc...That would be cleaner I think.

[I found this article led me to the solution....](http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx)

Comment: Nope - identity still gets out of sync so I am sticking with the above which consistently works as expected.

I just find this all a bit odd that the Identity cannot deal with it.